# Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android development
My eclipse was working properly. But now when I start a new project it give an error
Problem opening wizard
The selected wizard could not be opened

The Detailed error message is

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (239).
```

I can't run existing Android project also.But I can start a new java project and run.
Why this is happening

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have not added ADT then do the Following steps.

Help -> Add New Software -> Add.

In `Name` option write ADT

And if you have installed ADT in your Computer then add its path in `Location` like

`jar:file:/D:/ADT-16.0.1.zip!/`

And then ADT will install.

And if there is a problem try to remove that adt and install again.

```
1) remove the ADT repo (Window->Preferences->Install/Updates->Available Software Sites)
2) add Indigo repo ("http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo")
3) run updates
4) add ADT repo again and install
```

Answer (score 8):

For me,what seemed to work was:

1.Restarting the application
2.(Or) Restarting the computer

I still had some problems.Some projects dint load.I'm not sure what the problem is or was.I think reinstalling ADT should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is not necessary to uninstall the ADT plugin. Just add this repo(http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) and then help->check for updates

Answer (score 1):

I have been having a similar problem, and it seems to be the org.eclipse.objectteams plugin causing the trouble for me. What I needed to do was remove the plugin from my Eclipse plugin directory as follows:

```
mv ~/.eclipse/*/plugins/org.eclipse.objectteams* ~/someDIR
```

There seems to be dependency issues with the newer versions of Eclipse. Sorry if I can't provide more information.

Maybe see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350133.

Answer (score 1):

You will also get this fault if you have an AVD running. Close the AVD and restart eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Am posting this answer for the people who is referring this post in future.

The methods that all mentioned will take more time. I have figured out this problem by updating plugin.
But it is not like the way as vic12 is mentioned. I have done this in the following way

Help > Install new software > click on link ***What is already installed*** you can see a list of installed software. You can choose and update any one as you want. If you click check for update it will update all the software that we installed it will take a lot of time. By this way you can update the one that you want. This can be done in a minute. it saves time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case computer restart resolved all the issues without re-installing ADT plugin.
BTW, I am using MAC + ADT_v22

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help - eclipse market place - search for adt. Then update or install it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I have started to read answers above. then I stopped to read and just restarted eclipse and it is worked for me! (this is my first solution for all electronic devices and generally works :)

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if you remove Android from your build path. Just try to relink JRE6 or 7 and restart the program. Eclipse will handle it for you.

Comment: Please extend your answer and add instructions on how to relink JRE6 OR 7 if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved when I restarted Eclipse and changed the workspace am working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the workspace too. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac and user Eclipse ADT, go to ADT -> Preferences -> Android. There you should find an option for setting your Android SDK location. Simply browse for the existing ADT, and select the SDK folder.

This of course can only be done after the SDK has been installed.

[image: Android preference settings in Eclipse ADT]

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the eclipse. It seems eclipse is having some bug which is leading other components from proper loading. Or first of all start sdk manager from background and then eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
This is work for me. Please follow these steps. 
GO To:
Help>>Install New Software>>Available Software Sites
then Locate for:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

If available then just select and reload
Else 
ADD >> Location past this url in 
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo ">>OK Then >> Reload

Hope this help somebody .

Answer (score 0):

Enter the variable 'PATH' the path of the JRE folder (java).

Answer (score 0):

I hope that would help somebody:
I had the same problem and ironically the problem was in a simple code error. For some reason this error caused Eclipse to overreact with red lines all across the code and saving errors as well as the error mentioned in this post.

I fixed the problem (deleting an extra }) and all problems disappeared.

I don't know why Eclipse overreacted this time, but it's another option to check before you install, uninstall or update anything.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add this in here as the problem just occured with me. What I did was `close eclipse`, reopen it and then it started working. If this doesn't fix the issue then I advise you go with @Bhavin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might have stored two ADT plugins one with link and other with zip file you have to delete one of them
Help -> Install new software -> Available software for sites -> and remove one of adt plugins.