# Issues with DDMS in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, device, adb, ddms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151691/plug-in-com-android-ide-eclipse-adt-was-unable-to-load-class-android)

I update DDMS module in Android (Help> Check for Updates) but now when I start Eclipse this error occurs:

```
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ToolsLocator.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (802).
```

And even if I can see my attached device using 
    adb devices

I can't see it in DDMS > Devices (in Eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

just follow these steps :

in Eclipse Help > Install New Software > Work with: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ to Add repository named Android. Select all the Developer Tools   DDMS (Dalvik Debug Monitor Server) perspective, Development Tools, Hierarchy Viewer, Traceview. Accept the license and unsigned warning. Restart Eclipse.

Once installed, obtain updates in Help > Update.