# Not able to create Android application project in Eclipse. Error Message - Enter an application name (shown in launcher)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I want to create a fresh Android application project in Eclipse. But when I try to create a project it every time gives me the message on the first screen of creation.

**Enter an application name (shown in launcher)**

[image]

When I remove the theme also

[image]

I have already entered a name for that application.

I am using:

- Android api level 10
- Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2,Build id: 20120216-1857
- Operating System : Linux Fedora 17

There are projects which I am developing on the same machine.

I have several times restarted eclipse and my developing machine. What is happening?

This my sdk image for api level 17

[image]

Update from the solutions I got that my ADT plugin was not updated for Android sdk tools version 22. So now I have updated it but I have another error. See:

[image]

Comment: @user927258 Reinstalling sdk will be a very heavy task for me.

Comment: try selecting no theme because this theme is not available in froyo

Comment: can you show your sdk manager screen capture

Comment: @Iftikar Urrhman Khan One min

Comment: @Iftikar Urrhman Khan see my updated post. Do you want for api level 10 also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has been often occurred by Many People. you can see [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33770)

Solution given by them is to

> **Update ADT plugin and then SDK tools and after when you will try  to**
>    **create a new project, the error will not occur**

Hope this will Help.

Comment: Sir this is the exact solution for the problem. Thank you.

Comment: My ADT and SDK both are updated but still unable to create a new project. Please help..!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you don`t have any API installed to compile. First install an API version in SDK Manager and later try again to create a new project.

UPDATE:

If you update SDK Android, probably you must update ADT.

For the last error update eclipse.

Comment: ADT is updated? Eclipse is linked correctly with SDK Android?

Comment: This screen is for SDK, ADT is updated? "Help -> Install new software..." and check the repository [link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

Comment: previously it was not updated but now after also it is giving new error just updating the screen shot

Comment: have you seen the new screen shot

Comment: Add all these to your answers

Comment: Check your java version. Switch from Java 1.5 to Java 1.6

Comment: You can do this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151691/plug-in-com-android-ide-eclipse-adt-was-unable-to-load-class-android)

Comment: it is solved I have updated my ADT and then eclipse. It worked for me. Thanks Please put the comments summary in your answer so that any one gets benefited by it. Get back to me here when complete the updation.

Answer (score 1):

In `Eclipse, go to Window -> Android SDK Manager`. Select one or more SDK Platforms to install.
You have to install the sdk platforms before creating the Android application project.
See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK Manager

```
tools -> android sdk buid tools (Select last rev. and install the pack.)
```

thats worked for me.