# The New >> Project >> Android Application Project doesn't work

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The **New >> Project >> Android Application** Project doesn't work
I got these messages:

```
Problem Opening Wizard
The selected wizard could not be started

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (839).
```

Comment: Please, take a look into Android Studio http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html - Eclipse is going to be deprecated as Android IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the plug-in implementing your wizard could not be started. Have you tried using the **Error Log** or **Console** views to see why it couldn't be activated? 2 suggestions for you:

- First try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151691/plug-in-com-android-ide-eclipse-adt-was-unable-to-load-class-android) solutions.
- If not successful, try to reinstall your Eclipse from a newer build.
  That often solves the problem.

Comment: If it helped you then mark it as answer so that it can also help others who will face same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Eclipse perfectly works... And If you are still getting error in Package statement, you can build project manually by going through Project menu in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem solved when I restarted Eclipse and changed the workspace I was working on. try it.. that might help