# Error found when i restarted my eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-layout

I found this error when i restarted my eclipse.

```
"Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor."
```

Please let me know what should i do..
I am beginner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151691/plug-in-com-android-ide-eclipse-adt-was-unable-to-load-class-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly Close all xml files and class files and then restart eclipse....it will resolve the issue...it worked for me.....